# Result type from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Ok so I'm calling a stored procedure and I'm unsure of what type my VB.net code will be receiving.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
@IDNo varchar(Max)
AS
select a.IDNo,
        p.EMAIL
from person p 
    left join customer a on p.person_id=a.person_id
where (a.IDNo=@IDNo)
```

Here's my VB so far;

```
resultSet = thisDataCxt.sp_GetEmail(IDNo).FirstOrDefault()
```

My question is, what type should resultSet be? Can I make it an `Object`? If so how do I access its IDNo and EMAIL properties.

Also need to bear in mind I'm using this to see if there are no results back (aka IDNo didn't have a match) so I need to test if resultSet is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you use Dataset & datatables and store the sp output in that.Then try to iterate the values through it if datatable has more than 0 rows.

Comment: Sounds good. But say it returns the ID but not the email, how do I find that out from my datatable?

Comment: One more thing is you can execute the sproc in vb.net by supplying the input and out put parameters.by this you will get the output of sproc in the variable.

Comment: Your datarow would have a DBNull in the email field

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be whatever you've mapped the result of the `FunctionImport` sp_getEmail to, probably a `ComplexType`. It's not going to be a set, per se, as you're taking the FirstOrDefault.

Incidentally, prefixing your SPs with sp_ is bad practice. http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/

Comment: Not my system so can't change their naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code.

```
cmd.CommandText = "your proc name";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
                    param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    SqlParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Int, 8);
                    param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.OutPut;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now you have your output value in @param2.